# Typescript error on generated discriminated unions

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I'm trying to write a code that will generate a discriminated union for each member of a type and a function that will accept an object of that type and an instance of one of the union member.

here's the code I have so far

```js
interface RickAndMortyCharacter {
  species: string;
  origin: {
    name: string;
    url: string;
  };

}

type RickAndMortyCharacterChange = {
  [Prop in keyof RickAndMortyCharacter]: {
    updatedProps: Prop;
    newValue: RickAndMortyCharacter[Prop];
  };
}[keyof RickAndMortyCharacter];


function applyPropertyChange(
  state: RickAndMortyCharacter,
  payload: RickAndMortyCharacterChange
) {
  // Error on this line
  state[payload.updatedProps] = payload.newValue;

  return state;
}
```

Also available here with the typescript [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgErAQawIIgCYCyA9lGAJ4DCAFnFIpFMgN4BQyyAzgA4QLAQcAXJzBRQAcwDcbZCWDjQw1u3Yg4AWwjCOoidJXIArlAA223SCkyAvtJbWWLcjzQYc+YqUo06CBtThLFABeZhkAbQAFKCIuZFBkTAgyIhhXLFxCEnIA3wYAXSUZdkMuPDhIPGjYoWRqrn0VEAgAdwA1OBNDLXT3LK9c+mgomK58xtt7cKSUtPQMj2zvWiGocccWGEMQP2AiEGQ4Li4TMnroHJoggAoZHQqe+b7PS5W-aAAaGS44MhMiOB4YRPTIvZZ5aABIIsACUYXYAHoEcgAKJQGKMfbIMBUYAcZAmUAQO5gB7hH5-AF4AB0pXKlXqHHyyFCFP+gOpzXanW6dnYUAgYGMB3ukGkDhYSOQAHUaGB4sg8PsAOTy7Z4aD3fDxfE4lDbPYiiAQdS6ojIFokTAfeJgZX44DqLhEDgcYAAIxMKDA5oAROpgAAPX3Yqj6soPKqjfGBPChlBcjpdYkIfY6TjAtygpaDd5QKHiELwowRhnR4S+uQKEC+r6qVpJ7oV937ABWRGMvvsdlTIHTHAATJmFv1XhD81dCyzi3TI4yK9xePwOLWZImeT1lE0ND1fQAJCAmf6rgzGMzIfdEYBd9gOBxAA)

typescript gives me the following error

> Type 'string | { name: string; url: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string & { name: string; url: string; }'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string & { name: string; url: string; }'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; url: string; }'.(2322)

What is interesting is when i hover over the `RickAndMortyCharacterChange` type I see that the following type is declared:

```
type RickAndMortyCharacterChange = {
    updatedProps: "species";
    newValue: string;
} | {
    updatedProps: "origin";
    newValue: {
        name: string;
        url: string;
    };
}
```

Which seems to be right to me since Typescript prevents me from writing this

```
const s: RickAndMortyCharacterChange = {
  updatedProps: "origin",
  newValue: "bonjour"
};

const s2: RickAndMortyCharacterChange = {
  updatedProps: "species",
  newValue: {
    name: "Hello",
    url: "Hoi"
  }
}
```

I have used a very very similar method in an Angular project recently and it worked perfectly I can not understand why typescript complains here

Comment: This is the "correlated unions" issue as described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the recommended approach is to refactor types to generics as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wjDqYm). Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: It's perfect thanks for the links ! Yes if you want to write an answer I will upvote it and give it a thumb up !

Comment: @jcalz keeping the same code for generating the union i also found this [workaround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgErAQawIIgCYCyA9lGAJ4DCAFnFIpFMgN4BQyyAzgA4QLAQcAXJzBRQAcwDcbZCWDjQw1u3Yg4AWwjCOoidJXIArlAA223SCkyAvtJbWWLcjzQYc+YqUo06CBtThLFABeZhkAbQAFKCIuZFBkTAgyIhhXLFxCEnIA3wYAXSUZdkMuPDhIPGjYoWRqrn0VEAgAdwA1OBNDLXT3LK9c+mgomK58xtt7cKSUtPQMj2zvWiGocccWGEMQP2AiEGQ4Li4TMnroHJoggAoZHQqe+b7PS5W-aAAaGS44MhMiOB4YRPTIvZZ5aABIIsACUYXY90gyFCyhUADoMYiIF8DOEfn8AXg0aVypV6hxCsh8f9AWjmu1Ot0bI52FAIGBjAcsdIHEA)
Does it have any cons that the recommended approach does not have?

Comment: I guess it's worse performance wise

Comment: [It's much less type safe](https://tsplay.dev/WYLGgm), due to a bug at [ms/TS#37103](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37103).  You're just accidentally using a bug to suppress an error; the compiler isn't really verifying what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially a limitation of the TypeScript type checking algorithm, and the underlying issue is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  When you have an expression of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) and write code where that expression appears multiple times, the compiler analyzes it by treating each utterance of that expression as if it were independent of the original.  So given something like

```
declare const state: RickAndMortyCharacter;
declare const payload: {
    updatedProps: "species";
    newValue: string;
} | {
    updatedProps: "origin";
    newValue: {
        name: string;
        url: string;
    };
}
```

you get this:

```
const up = payload.updatedProps;
// const up: "species" | "origin"
const nv = payload.newValue;
// const nv: string | { name: string; url: string; }
```

Note that `up` and `nv` are both of union types. But that has lost information you care about.  If all you know about `up` is that it's of type `"species" | "origin"`, and all you know about `nv` is that it's of type `string | { name: string; url: string}`, then you can't write this anymore without an error:

```
state[up] = nv; // error!
```

Because what if `up` is `"origin"` but `nv` is a `string`?  You only know that's impossible because both `up` and `nv` came from the same `payload`.  But TypeScript doesn't analyze the *identity* of `payload`, it's looking at the *type*.  There's no such thing as "correlated unions" in TypeScript.

So the assignment fails, even though it's 100% type safe.  And they can't fix it by just making the compiler analyze `state[up] = nv` multiple times, without either massively destroying compiler performance or making the compiler unpredictable.  See [this twitter thread by the TS Team dev lead](https://twitter.com/SeaRyanC/status/1544414378383925250).

---

Luckily, there is a way to refactor the code so that the compiler does follow the logic.  It's described at [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  The approach is to replace unions with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) that range over keylike types, and then perform generic [indexes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into appropriate [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html). These indexes-into-mapped types can happen inside a single *distributive object type* (as coined in that GitHub issue).

Your `RickAndMortyCharacterChange` is essentially such a type, but you can change it to make it generic (and still default to the full union):

```
type RickAndMortyCharacterChange<K extends keyof RickAndMortyCharacter
  = keyof RickAndMortyCharacter> = {
    [P in K]: {
      updatedProps: P;
      newValue: RickAndMortyCharacter[P];
    };
  }[K];
```

And now `applyPropertyChange()` can be made generic in `K` constrained to `keyof RickAndMortyCharacter`.  You will pass in a value of type `RickAndMortyCharacterChange<K>`, and suddenly everything works:

```
function applyPropertyChange<K extends keyof RickAndMortyCharacter>(
  state: RickAndMortyCharacter,
  payload: RickAndMortyCharacterChange<K>
) {
  state[payload.updatedProps] = payload.newValue; // okay
  return state;
}
```

If you break that into `up` and `nv` you'll see why:

```
function applyPropertyChange<K extends keyof RickAndMortyCharacter>(
  state: RickAndMortyCharacter,
  payload: RickAndMortyCharacterChange<K>
) {
  const up = payload.updatedProps;
  // const up: K
  const nv = payload.newValue;
  // RickAndMortyCharacter[K]
  state[up] = nv; // okay
  return state;
}
```

Now `up` is of type `K` and `nv` is of type `RickAndMortyCharacter[K]`.  They are both generic.  And the assignment is seen as assigning a `RickAndMortyCharacter[K]` on the right to a `RickAndMortyCharacter[K]` on the left.  Since these types are identical generics, everything works as desired.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgErAQawIIgCYCyA9lGAJ4DCAFnFIpFMgN4BQyyAzgA4QLAQcAXJzBRQAcwDcbZCWDjQw1u3Yg4AWwjCOoidJXIArlAA223SCkyAvtOssW5Hmgw58xUpRp0EDanEsIAB4AaWQIAA9IfA5kTAgyIhgXLFxCEnJ-HwYZAF44hKSUt3TPLPpoAD5kfOUVAG0ABWRQZBCAXSUZA0MuPDhIPEaoIi4hZEb9A2QQCAB3ADU4E0MtYrSPTO8KqCb2qfZbG3qO6UcyZ1Qa9fcMr1od-0CHFjxeE1oUBCIQHREBtboVK3MrbXzQaRvBAfKBfH5-LhwMgmIhwPBddi9fqDYajcYAIm4vH4HHxU1mi2Wq3MYksdmQAB9mDIsQChiMxsJ8XIFCAyTIKUsVms6qoNGsdLSrD1TDS9DY7Cxvr8wEYuNdEcjUXgAHSsnEcjjSAD0xuQyr+vS5RL4AnxjOQ3LEvPxSvhqpAADcNUiUWidYKqRATWaLR7PXLLA6mDNxZGpEZZSIpZJkPYdAD6r12tcvanTeEoCMoABCBwwQwgXzAH7IOBcLgmMi4niggLiYJhSLRPCxeKJZJAkqbe7ZKoAChkGcgwiHGzu5XBUAANDJNX70TdSlsHkunh3QpUWABKZnsMNqn1a-36iDsvFTAsXq1tGQXr1XjcB+ZC1aPs1ziCO5jrsHRTmAmbrtqep9GyLYcDm+RQf6gbClMsJgMYID-JAiosAWADqNCqsAyB4D8ADkqqVm8UAZvgLSxGAVAoJWNbYRwEAQOoTFEMgcwkJgy4tGAFGxMA6hcEQHAcMAABGJgoGAfH4uowARPazGsbBBp4nWDFaTMP5Bm6KqcLOrjzm2IH7igtQsjpd7wVyPKgPiq6qMZwpcnJPwAFZEMYrpHKZfwcAATBZwLbqOjw0IE1x1Le96co6Noku5ApedSZ4qGomhcgAEhAJgoplMpmI6hVEMArqHCw9hAA)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on to jcalz awesome answer, you can make a utility type so you can easily apply this pattern to any object type:

```js
type PropertyChange<T extends Object, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = {
  [P in K]: {
    updatedProps: P;
    newValue: T[P];
  };
}[K];

function applyPropertyChange<T extends Object, K extends keyof T = keyof T>(
  state: T,
  payload: PropertyChange<T, K>
) {
  state[payload.updatedProps] = payload.newValue;
  return state;
}
```

Usage

```js
const character: RickAndMortyCharacter = {
  species: 'initial species',
  origin: { name: '', url: '' },
};

const change: PropertyChange<RickAndMortyCharacter> = {
  updatedProps: 'species',
  newValue: 'new species',
}; // ok

const change2: PropertyChange<RickAndMortyCharacter> = {
  updatedProps: 'origin',
  newValue: '',
}; // error

applyPropertyChange(character, change); // ok

applyPropertyChange(
  character, 
  { updatedProps: 'origin', newValue: '' }
); // error

applyPropertyChange(
  character, 
  { updatedProps: 'species', newValue: '' }
); // ok

applyPropertyChange(
  { prop1: 'string' },
  { updatedProps: 'prop1', newValue: 'new string' }
); // ok

applyPropertyChange(
  { prop1: 1 },
  { updatedProps: 'prop1', newValue: 'new string' }
); // error

applyPropertyChange<{ prop1: number }>(
  { prop1: 'string' },
  { updatedProps: 'prop1', newValue: 'new string' }
); // error
```